# Deja-Dup: The existing backup is of a computer named

Tags: deja-dup

So this is a bit tricky for me to explain and am sure I can use a better title but here is my shot at explaining this.
So a few days back I was playing with a VM in GNOME-Boxes and eventually it crashed leaving me having to use my backups to try and restore the state of my VM's, this did not work initially so I waited a weak before trying to repair my backup drive. Any how, after a week of failing to create a backup I finally got one done yesterday.

The PROBLEM: I create backups on a daily. When it will work. Which wasn't a problem until last week. I woke up this morning and tried to perform a scheduled backup. Inserted my password and this was returned:

```
The existing backup is of a computer named MyPCname, but the current computers's name is MyPCname.phub.net.cable.rogers.com. If this is unexpected, you should back up to a different location.
```

This is unexpected although how would this even happen, and what is happening? How are my backups being tied with my ISP? How is this even a thing?

I am using **Ubuntu 20.10 64-bit, GNOME Version 3.38.3 X11**

Please ask me to include any information I may be missing. Thank you. Really could use some assistance. Not sure if I should be concerned or not. Appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, none of the proposed edits to `/etc/hosts` worked until I disconnected the wifi and added the following edits to the file:

```
127.0.0.1   Machine_name localhost
127.0.1.1   Machine_name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     Machine_name ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 Machine_name ip6-localnet
```

Then rebooted (with the wifi still OFF). There are a few other lines in the file, but they seem not to be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly uncommon, but not too difficult to fix. You can change your host name in a few steps:

0. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
1. Confirm the host name is not what you would like:

   ```
   cat /etc/hostname
   ```

   If you see `MyPCname.phub.net.cable.rogers.com`, then let’s continue.
2. Change your host name:

   ```
   sudo hostname MyPCname
   ```
3. Update the `hostname` file so the change persists after a reboot:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/hostname
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor you are comfortable with. Be sure to open the file with `sudo`, though.</sub>

   Change the `hostname` value to match your proper hostname.
4. Edit the `hosts` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/hosts
   ```

   Change the hostname for `127.0.0.1` and `::1`.

That’s all. You should be able to backup the computer and continue with your current Déjà Dup archive

Comment: MyPCname.phub.net.cable.rogers.com is what Deja-Dup will say it is named. I have taken the following steps you recommended although everything was as expected. Still experiencing the issue. But thank you for this attempt.